# User-generated SQL Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, postgresql-9.1

I'm developing a data warehouse using Ruby on Rails and I should allow the user to perform arbitrary SELECT queries on the application database.

I know this is what you usually SHOULDN'T do, but it's an interface my client actually needs (I can't think of all the possible queries the user might want to do and translate them to ActiveRecord queries). There could be complex joins and sub-queries and so on.
I'd rather do this (integrate it to my app) than let them access the DB via pgAdmin (I'm using postgresql).

My question is: what is the safest way of doing this? I should be able to escape anything like INSERT, UPDATE, DROP TABLE, etc...

I'm thinking of getting the query string and sanitizing these "dangerous" words and then using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sanitized_sql_string).
Is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: You are right that it is dangerous to let users **type** their own SQL.  You can lock down the rights to they can't corrupt your database, but you can't keep them from joining tables incorrectly, which may create a **runaway query**.  Andyne (sp?) used to have a product called GQL (graphical query language) which let the user click objects and lines to graphically create a query.  It did the work behind the scenes to create **good** SQL.  You could take a similar approach so that users 1) don't have to learn your database model, and 2) don't have to know SQL to build an ad-hoc query.

Comment: You might be better off with a store bought product like crystal reports or business objects.  In fact, Microsoft Access with linked tables is not all that bad.

Comment: I dunno, I might be alone here but I think allowing ad-hoc queries is perfectly fine if done right.  This is obviously a power tool meant for only certain users who know SQL.  Some lame editor will always have limitations; I've still yet to see any that I find usable.  The security in Postgres is great if used correctly, and you can avoid *runaway queries* by setting the query timeout to like 5 seconds or something.  Keep in mind, [StackOverflow](http://data.stackexchange.com/) actually permits ad-hoc queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safest way would be to let Postgres handle this security for you.  Create a new user:

```
CREATE USER Reader; -- Your Rails app should logon with this user
```

Then, *explicitly* grant `SELECT` permissions on the objects you want them to be able to query:

```
GRANT INSERT ON TableFoo TO Reader;
GRANT INSERT ON TableBar TO Reader;
```

Then, they'll be able to run arbitrary `SELECT` queries from these two tables, but if they try an `INSERT`, they'll get *Permission denied.*  You can then trap those security exceptions and handle them in your UI appropriately.

Comment: You'll need to `GRANT` rights on the schemas that contain the tables of interest too. This is without a doubt the correct approach. Whether you can convince Rails to log in with different users for different purposes is another thing entirely, though..

Comment: I like this approach. The thing is, I need to access the same models with different connections, so I'll eventually need to execute the query in a non read only environment (I use the query result to update other models). What I'm thinking of doing is validating the query using a readonly user before saving it for future, real life use. Does that sound reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

Create the application then create the database.

After this, in your database configuration (`database.yml`), connect to the database with some  non-default user, say `lame_user`. Create this `lame_user` on your RDBMS, in your case PostgreSQL, and grant him only SELECT permissions on all of your tables.
You will now have the user `postgres` and the `lame_user` that can access your database, but only `postgres` can do all the stuff.

If the user tries to do anything besides SELECT's, an error will occur.

Resuming: Make this application constraint a database thing. It will be easier.